# Translating SSL command to PHP

Tags: php, ssl

I have an SSL command which signs a string with a given key:
`openssl dgst -sha256 -hex -sign key.pem data.txt`. I'd like to know how I can translate it to a PHP function. The equivalent in PHP should be something like this:
`openssl_sign($data, $signature, $key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256)`. However, the unix command outputs the signature in hex, while the I don't really get what the PHP command outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will produce the same hex representation as the openssl command:

```
$signature = "";
$data = file_get_contents("data.txt");
$key = file_get_contents("key.pem");
openssl_sign($data, $signature, $key, OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA256);
echo bin2hex($signature);
```

Essentially, the php version produces the binary bytes, so in my code above, I just use the bin2hex function to output it in the same format you are used to in the openssl command.

Comment: Thanks! I'm having a bit of a trouble generating a valid key with PHP. I use the following command: `base64_encode(hex2bin($key))`. Example output: `lnFOGfdh2pRSCmjTDJlD5QTnyRGmmFgg01WpT2mI8Ic=`. However, it's not accepted by the openssl_sign function we used above. But when I generate a new private key using SSL, it does work.

Comment: Are you storing the signature in a file? If so, the openssl command puts 'RSA-SHA256(data.txt)= ' in front of the actual hex output. Do you need to do the same in the PHP solution?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I referred to the creation of the private key, not signing the signature (I guess a bit off-topic). So the question is, how can I generate a valid key (accepted by openssl_sign), from a given string. In my case I tried using `base64_encode(hex2bin($string));` but it seems like the output is not accepted by openssl_sign.

Comment: I verified with `https://holtstrom.com/michael/tools/hextopem.php` and the output is okay. But why when I try to use `lnFOGfdh2pRSCmjTDJlD5QTnyRGmmFgg01WpT2mI8Ic=` as the key for openssl_sign, I don't get an output?